# Differential equation $ y'= \log(ax+by+c)~ ;a,b,c \in R$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$ y'= \log(ax+by+c)~ ;\qquad  a,b,c \in R$$

So is this how I am supoosed to ask questions here?

Comment: Hi panush: welcome to math.SE. I've "texified" your mathematics input. Please consult [this discussion on Meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/934/where-is-the-latex-reference-please) on how to do it yourself in the future. Etiquette wise, it is generally expected that you give a bit more information than just an equation. Is this for school work? What do you want to find? Things like that. And generally just try to be polite. Cheers!

Comment: This is how you would ask questions to Wolfram alpha. In this forum there are people answering which usually enjoy a bit more interaction...

Comment: I'm sorry about how I asked the question. I've only read the faq, so I didn't know how to ask properly. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can "solve" this equation by [separation of variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables). First introduce a new function $z(x)= a x + b y(x) + c$. In terms of this function the differential equation reads
$$ z'(x) = b \log z(x) +a$$
and is separable (as it does not depend explicitly on $x$). An (implicit) solution reads
$$ \int_{z_0}^z dz' \frac{1}{b \log z' +a} = x- x_0$$
with the initial condition $z(x_0)  =z_0$ which corresponds to $y(x_0) = (z_0 -a x_0 -c)/b$ in terms of the old variables. The integral can be evaluated and gives (it is rather ugly looking)
$$ \frac{e^{-a/b} \text{Ei}\left( \frac{a}{b} + \log z \right)}{b} = x-x_0 + \frac{e^{-a/b} \text{Ei}\left( \frac{a}{b} + \log z_0 \right)}{b},$$
with Ei the [exponential integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral). Being able to solve explicitly for $z(x)$ or $y(x)$ seems to be unlikely.